# Assign points to their respective distributions with a one to one correspondance

Tags: probability, distributions

I have to determine what are the likelyhoods of four points being associated with four different distributions.
Knowing that they can only be part of one and only one distribution at the given time.

I have these four distributions, of an image being rotated up, left, right, down. [image]
Here is their histogram :
[image]

They have been taken over a sample of 100 images, by hand.

We have 100 samples for every distribution, so the prior likelyhood for each of them is 0.25.

the values are just a metric for confidence.

Now lets say that I get four new samples but this time I don't know which one correspondes to which.  I only know that it follows these distributions and that every sample is taken from one of them.

My end result would look like :
Xa is part of the blue distribution with a likelyhood of 12%
Xb is part of the orange distribution with a likelyhood of 30%
Xc is part of the green distribution with a likelyhood of 60%
Xd is part of the red distribution with a likelyhood of 45%

The goal being to be able to tell how likely is it that this new point (lets say Xc) is the one facing down with 56% likelyhood

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can't answer this until you posit a *prior distribution* for the four distributions.

Comment: @whuber I might be wrong but, but can't we estimate a posterior from the plots we have ? 
And what if we didi ? Let's say I managed to get the posterios how should I proceed ?

Comment: You cannot estimate a posterior without a prior.

Comment: Why not estimate the underlying distributions with their respective eCDFs?

Comment: @jblood94, I guess I can estimate what their distribution are. But I don't think that's unless I am missing something( If the comment was directed to me).

Comment: @whuber, the prior is for every distribution a normal one( the small bumps on the left is just noise)
that can (again, unless I missed something) converge to the right parameters.

Comment: That's not a prior.  A prior assigns four probabilities, one per distribution, that sum to unity.

Comment: What @whuber means is that you need to specify how much each color contributes to the mixture. If there are a trillion blue points for every one red point, then a point with $x=0.2$ is more likely to be blue than red, despite red being the higher graph (greater likelihood) at that point.

Comment: @Dave, I see thanks, that's not at all what I understood. 
We have 100 samples for each distribution.

Comment: That’s extremely important information and corresponds to each of your four distributions having a prior probability of $0.25$. Please edit this information into your original post, as comments can get ignored and deleted. // Do you get why a trillion-to-one blue-to-red ratio results in blue being more probable at $x=0.2$ despite red being higher at that point?

Comment: @Dave, Indeed, thanks ! I understand a bit more. Now I see what was whuber talking about when he was asking about a prior. 
So here the prior would be 0.25  for a new sample then with the data we collected we the posterio is the distributions we got ?

I added the information as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from the question how the four new points are sampled. This answer assumes each of the four distributions is sampled to obtain the four new points (i.e., one point per distribution).

There are $4!=24$ ways the new samples could be arranged relative to the distributions. If the new samples are presented in a random order, the prior probability is uniform over each permutation.

One approach is to create a kernel density estimate of the PDF of the underlying distributions based on the 100 samples. Use that to get the likelihood of each of the 24 permutations. From there get the likelihood of each sample/distribution pair.

Example R code:

```
set.seed(29229979)
# actual 100 samples x 4 measures go here
vals <- lapply(1:4, function(i) rgamma(100, i))
# actual 4 new samples go here
x <- rgamma(4, 1:4)
x
#> [1] 0.4398417 0.2718655 1.4078939 4.0912583
# use a kernel density to approximate the PDF of the underlying distributions
dens <- lapply(1:4, function(i) with(density(vals[[i]]), approxfun(x, y, rule = 2)))
# all 24 ways the samples could be arranged relative to the distributions
n <- gtools::permutations(4, 4) # distribution = column; sample = value
p <- n
# get the likelihood of each permutation
for (i in 1:4) p[,i] <- dens[[i]](x[n[,i]])
p <- Rfast::rowprods(p)
p <- p/sum(p)
# get the likelihoods that each sample belongs to each distribution
d <- matrix(0, 4, 4, dimnames = list(paste0("sample", 1:4), paste0("distribution", 1:4)))
for (i in 1:4) for (j in 1:4) d[i, j] <- sum(p[n[,j] == i])
d
#>         distribution1 distribution2 distribution3 distribution4
#> sample1   0.398767127    0.34487889     0.1985968    0.05775719
#> sample2   0.511722207    0.28505003     0.1589338    0.04429400
#> sample3   0.081992265    0.31290982     0.4118571    0.19324080
#> sample4   0.007518401    0.05716126     0.2306123    0.70470800
# sanity checks
rowSums(d)
#> sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 
#>       1       1       1       1
colSums(d)
#> distribution1 distribution2 distribution3 distribution4 
#>             1             1             1             1
```

Note that the distributions plotted overlap considerably, so the results will not be decisive.